# postgresql, taking up alot of memory, and many processes

Tags: postgresql

Suddenly we are having a memory issue on our server and I think it's due to postgres

Our replicating slave went down and still down, and I think it causes postgres to choak?

when I do `ps -ef` I see lots of the following lines

```
postgres 31161 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.22.123(53570) INSERT waiting for 26C/F5875798
postgres 31175 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.30.130(36126) INSERT
postgres 31176 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.30.130(36124) INSERT waiting for 26C/F645AB88
postgres 31177 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.30.130(36128) INSERT waiting for 26C/F644A6B8
postgres 31210 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.29.17(51158) INSERT
postgres 31250 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.19.52(36284) UPDATE
postgres 31251 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.19.52(36286) INSERT waiting for 26C/F5C32028
postgres 31252 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.19.52(36288) INSERT
postgres 31387 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.22.54(42988) INSERT
postgres 31389 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.22.54(42986) INSERT
postgres 31434 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.30.116(33648) UPDATE
postgres 31859 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.30.13(33494) INSERT
postgres 31861 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.30.13(33496) INSERT
postgres 31886 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.29.48(34408) UPDATE
postgres 31888 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.29.48(34410) INSERT waiting
postgres 31936 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.26.115(50432) INSERT waiting for 26C/F5C59038
postgres 31937 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.26.115(50428) UPDATE waiting
postgres 31938 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.26.115(50430) UPDATE waiting for 26C/F5C4AA48
postgres 32233 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.29.17(51240) INSERT
postgres 32297 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.24.193(56344) INSERT waiting for 26C/F58CCD90
postgres 32298 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.24.193(56342) INSERT waiting
postgres 32299 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.24.193(56346) INSERT waiting
postgres 32703 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.24.99(50452) INSERT
postgres 32705 13564  0 Aug22 ?        00:00:00 postgres: momsplanner littlehome_db x.x1.24.99(50454) INSERT waiting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7 of them seem to be waiting for syncrep (presumably from your defunct replica). Do you intentionally have synchronous replication set up? You either need to get your replica back running ASAP, or turn off synchronous replication.  Another 5 are waiting on locks, maybe ones held by those first 7.

On the other hand, 12 of them don't seem to be blocked. It is hard to say what is going on with them. If you were using synchronous replication consistently, I would expect almost every connection to soon be piled up on it, not just half of them.

It is also odd to see 11 different IP addresses connected to a database named "littlehome_db".  Are all those connections authorized and welcome?

Comment: Thanks for answer, I had barman setup and streaming replica as well, I don't know if it is synchrnous replication, I guess one of them is. So I turned them off and the problem seems to be gone